# Rspec testing raising and rescue of method

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, raiserror

Is there a way to rspec test if an error was raised and rescued? If I have a rescue, my rspec test does not see the raised error, only results in the rescue?

```
module MyApp
  def some_method(msg)
     raise StandardError.new(msg)
  end

  def second_method(msg)
    begin
      count = 0
      some_method(msg)
    rescue StandardError=> e
      puts e
      count = 1
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe Myapp do
  describe "#some_method" do
    it "should raise error" do
       expect {
        some_method("this is an error")
      }.to raise_error(StandardError) {|e|
        expect(e.message).to eql "this is an error"
      }
    end
  end

  # this fails, as the error is not raised
  describe "#second_method" do
    it should raise error and rescue do
      expect {
        a = second_method("this is an error and rescue")
      }.to raise_error(StandardError) {|e|
        expect(e.message).to eql "this is an error and rescue"
        expect(a) = 1
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is possibly an X/Y problem. By definition, if you've rescued an exception, it is no longer "raised" unless you re-raise it. If you want to track previously-handled exceptions, you'll need to manage your own storage object to persist outside of rescue/ensure clauses to track $! and $@.

Comment: What does $! and $@mean?

Comment: Ruby makes a nod back to Larry Wall by maintaining a number of cryptic system global variables, of which `$!` and `$@` are two. If you `require 'English'` at the top of your file you can call them by the more descriptive names `$ERROR_INFO` and `$ERROR_POS`

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to raise or rescue StandardError directly because it's pretty uninformative, and won't catch errors outside of the [StandardError hierarchy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Exception.html#class-Exception-label-Built-In+Exception+Classes). Instead, you generally want to test that a specific exception was raised, or that a specific error class or error message was raised.

If you know the custom or [built-in exception class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Exception.html#class-Exception-label-Built-In+Exception+Classes) that you want, or the specific error message, then test for that explicitly. For example:

```
it 'should raise an ArgumentError exception' do
  expect { MyApp.new.foo }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
end

it 'should raise MyCustomError' do
  expect { MyApp.new.foo }.to raise_error(MyCustomError)
end

it 'should raise StandardError with a custom message' do
  msg = 'this is a custom error and rescue'
  expect { MyApp.new.foo }.to raise_error(msg)
end
```

If you don't know (or care about) the specific exception or message that should be raised, but you expect *some* exception to interrupt the execution flow, then you should use a bare [raise_error](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) matcher. For example:

```
it "should raise an exception" do
  expect { MyApp.new.foo }.to raise_error
end
```

Comment: thank you for your post, but unless I misunderstand, I do not believe it addresses my question. (I used standarderror as an example, it's normally a specific error.)